# How to use $(this) inside a 'sub function' in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function

This function call

```
$('#mydiv').paintRed();
```

paints the background of the DOM element with id **mydiv** red, if you're using this code:

```
$.fn.paintRed = function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Well, okay. But now I want to 'group' my own functions. Now I want the programmer to use this function call to achieve the same as above:

```
$('#mydiv').subsub.paintRed();
```

How do I achieve that?

(Or else, if above request is not possible, is there any other way?)

Comment: It's not possible. `this` would refer to `$('#mydiv').subsub` (unless you bind it to another value but that means creating a new function for each selection). That's how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $.fn.subsub= function() {
       var that = this;
        return {
            "paintRed" : function(){
                $(that).css("background-color", "red");
            },
            "yourOwnFunction1" : function(){
                 //code here
             },
            "yourOwnFunction2" : function(){
                 //code here
             }
        };
    }
    $("#mydiv").subsub().paintRed();
//  $("#mydiv").subsub().yourOwnFunction1();
```

Return an Object that has `paintRed` as its property. By using this method all your functions can be "grouped" into the `subsub` function.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy7Mg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can extend functions using jquery

```
$.fn.someFunctionName = function(){
// do something
}
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anupam/ZCuLj/) here

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my question.